# I don't wash my hands and never get sick. Any theories?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, pathology

I have only been sick a few times in my life(I'm 21 and probably 3-4 times) and even when I am sick I don't feel that bad and I am over it within a day or two. My family has always given me slack for never washing my hands but I see no point unless they physically look dirty. Unlike me though my family gets sick around the same amount as other people(a couple times a year).

I have this theory that since my body is always exposed to germs and other bacteria that it is stronger and able to fight off most colds before they ever happen. This theory obviously contradicts popular opinion and what doctors recommend but I have always felt fine not washing.

What do you guys think?

Comment: it's well known that exposure to germs at a low level improves the immune system, but not washing your hands also increases the risk of exposure to doses of germs large enough to cause sickness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may very well be strengthening your immune system, but there are microorganisms that you don't want to get, which can have longer term health consequences. For example, there seems to be a significant increase in developing MS if you've ever had the Epstein-Barr virus. But this is just one case. You also don't want Salmonella, tape worms, etc.

So there may be a price to pay for a stronger immune system: namely higher probability of exposing yourself to the more dangerous things out there.

Comment: That is a minor fear of mine but the way I see it a lot of these diseases/infections are spread many other ways than through just being picked up on your hand. eg breathing them in/eating them etc. In which case a stronger immune system would be beneficial in fighting things off that may have nothing to do with washing your hands.